# SQL Assignment query

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have 2 databases - one with customers' data and the second one with discount codes. I would like to assign code to each customer. The code can be assigned only once, so I would like to mark the code as 'used' once it is assigned. The codes should be assigned only to those customers that don't have a code assigned. Unused code can be assigned to any customer.

CUSTOMER_DATABASE:

| CUSTOMER ID | CUSTOMER CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6f73js |
| 2 |  |
| ... | ... |

DATA_DISCOUNT_CODES:

| ID | CODE | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6f73js | USED |
| 2 | kdw45s |  |
| ... | ... | ... |

Could you please help me write SQL query for this, using MySQL 8.0 syntax?

Comment: How many customers do you have - approx? How many discount_codes?

Comment: I have 10 000 codes, but I can add new codes to the datebase. It would be the best if the query could select codes from a source database.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky as you have to generate ROW_NUMBERs for both tables to join them.

IF you want only to include certain customers you need further criteria than `CUSTOMER CODE` IS NULL.

And a word of advise, don't use spaces in your column names, you need to encapsulate them always with backticks, that makes much more work, than having column names that lack spaces.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_DATABASE (
>   `CUSTOMER ID` INTEGER,
>   `CUSTOMER CODE` VARCHAR(6)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_DATABASE
>   (`CUSTOMER ID`, `CUSTOMER CODE`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '6f73js'),
>   ('2', NULL),
>   
>   ('3', NULL);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE DATA_DISCOUNT_CODES (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `CODE` VARCHAR(6),
>   `STATUS` VARCHAR(4)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO DATA_DISCOUNT_CODES
>   (`ID`, `CODE`, `STATUS`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '6f73js', 'USED'),
>   ('2', 'kdw45s', NULL),
>   ('3', 'and43d', NULL);
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE CUSTOMER_DATABASE T1
> INNER JOIN (SELECT `CUSTOMER ID`
> , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()  rown 
> FROM CUSTOMER_DATABASE WHERE `CUSTOMER CODE` IS NULL) T2 ON T1.`CUSTOMER ID` = T2.`CUSTOMER ID`
> INNER JOIN (SELECT `CODE`
> , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()  rown 
> FROM DATA_DISCOUNT_CODES 
> WHERE `STATUS` IS NULL) T3 ON T2.rown = T3.rown
> INNER JOIN DATA_DISCOUNT_CODES T4 ON T3.`CODE` =  T4.`CODE`
> SET T1.`CUSTOMER CODE` = T4.`CODE`,
>       T4.`STATUS` = 'USED'
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_DATABASE;
> ```
>
> ```
> CUSTOMER ID | CUSTOMER CODE
> ----------: | :------------
>           1 | 6f73js       
>           2 | kdw45s       
>           3 | and43d
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM DATA_DISCOUNT_CODES
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | CODE   | STATUS
> -: | :----- | :-----
>  1 | 6f73js | USED  
>  2 | kdw45s | USED  
>  3 | and43d | USED
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4dcd6a166bb00d8a7c2820baee6d52a1)*

Comment: Thank you, but there's one problem. Here you used INSERT INTO ... VALUES to enter 3 example values, but my database with codes has 10 000 records, so I can't import them manually. Can I use INSERT INTO... SELECT? 

CREATE TABLE DATA_DISCOUNT_CODES (
  ID INTEGER,
  CODE VARCHAR(32),
  STATUS VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO DATA_DISCOUNT_CODES (CODE)
SELECT COUPON  FROM SOURCE_DATABASE;

COUPON is the name of the column where all the codes are stored.

Comment: Also here you defined in CREATE TABLE which code is used and which is null. I want to run this query every day. For the first time this query should assign a code to each customer, because none of them has a code. Every other time the CUSTOMER_DATABASE will be updated with new customers, so they won't have a code assigned until the query will be run.

Comment: ito show the that ot works, i must have data, my create table are only for this purpose made, and to be franc it this should be your work, so you can enter data in your databse as you see fit, you don't nbeed to do the dame as  did. For the query, you see that every customer who hasn' a code ois goven a number and all notg assigned codes as well and then the are mixed in the update, you can't change the logoc there but you can change the inner selects to select special customers. Further when you don't have e3nough customer for all codes or not enough codes for the available customers,

Comment: nothig happems until you run the code again, the rewst makes the update all by itself